# For std::cin, is there a situation where only EOFBIT is set but not FAILBIT?

Tags: c++, cin, eof, istream

I'm a complete beginner who's trying to wrap my head around how the std::istream works.

Ran a few test cases (on a Windows Machine - Windows Version 6.3.9600) with this simple program I wrote:

```
int main()
{
    char ch{0};
    while (true)
    {
        if (cin >> ch)
        {
            cout << ch << " is read. ASCII Code: " << int(ch)
                << " current state of cin : " << bitset<3> (cin.rdstate())
                << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            //cin.fail()
            cout << "Read failed. Current state of cin: "
                << bitset<3> (cin.rdstate()) << endl;
            cin.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

I should note that on my machine, `ios_base::failbit = 100` and `ios_base::eofbit = 010`

**Sample input 1: 12345[CTRL-Z]**

Which outputs:

```
1 is read. ASCII Code: 49 Current state of cin: 000
2 is read. ASCII Code: 50 Current state of cin: 000
3 is read. ASCII Code: 51 Current state of cin: 000
4 is read. ASCII Code: 52 Current state of cin: 000
5 is read. ASCII Code: 53 Current state of cin: 000
→ is read. ASCII Code: 26 Current state of cin: 000
```

At which point the program waits for further input.

**Sample input 2: 12345[CTRL-Z]6789**

Which outputs:

```
1 is read. ASCII Code: 49 Current state of cin: 000
2 is read. ASCII Code: 50 Current state of cin: 000
3 is read. ASCII Code: 51 Current state of cin: 000
4 is read. ASCII Code: 52 Current state of cin: 000
5 is read. ASCII Code: 53 Current state of cin: 000
→ is read. ASCII Code: 26 Current state of cin: 000
```

...Waits for further input. 
Still no flags were set, but the characters after the CTRL-Z gets ignored entirely, as if they were removed from the stream. Why isn't EOFBIT triggered here? I've also looked up the Substitute Character (ASCII Code 26), which is supposed to be non-printable, yet it still prints with a right arrow symbol (Why?). And since eofbit isn't triggered at the point it was read, I assume that Windows does not treat the Substitute character as an EOF character...

**Sample Input 3: [CTRL-Z]**

Output:

```
Read failed. Current state of cin: 110
```

Both eofbit and failbit are set when the input buffer is empty except for the [CTRL-Z] character.

**Sample input 4: [CTRL-Z] 123456789**

Output:

```
Read failed. Current state of cin: 110
```

Same output as third case, and the stuff that comes after [CTRL-Z] gets ignored.

It seemslike there isn't a case where cin successfully reads the [CTRL-Z] as an EOF character (that is, eofbit is set, but failbit is not). In the cases where cin DOES reads [CTRL-Z] as a character, it doesn't treat it as an EOF character (eofbit not set in samples 1 and 2).

What am I missing?

Comment: https://latedev.wordpress.com/2012/12/04/all-about-eof/ may help

Comment: Answering the question in the title, unformatted functions, like `cin.get(buffer, size)`, set `eofbit` when they reach end of file, and `failbit` only if they couldn't read even one character. Though the body of your post doesn't seem to bear any relation to the title - it's mostly about what Ctrl+Z does to console input.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That makes sense. But how does cin recognize the end of file? So in sample input 1 and 2, it clearly didn't regard the CTRL-Z as an eof, since eofbit is not triggered. But for 3 and 4, it does.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik To clarify, the title and the body of the post related in the following sense: i can't seem to come up with a test case from the console that sets the eofbit without also setting the failbit.

Comment: Windows is not Linux; `istream` is not provided by OS-level components. "Windows Version 6.3.9600" is not relevant, the compiler version is.